# How to prevent edit option on the x-ticks and y-ticks of plotly charts in R

Tags: r, plotly

I accidentally saw this functionality in `plotly` chart where you can edit the x and y ticks. Now, how can I prevent this editing feature.

Example code:

```
library(plotly)
library(palmerpenguins)

data("penguins")


p <- plot_ly(data = penguins, x = ~bill_length_mm, y = ~bill_depth_mm, 
             color = ~species, 
             type = "scatter", 
             mode = "markers",
             marker = list(size = 10)) %>%
  layout(title = "Penguin Bill Dimensions",
         xaxis = list(title = "Bill Length (mm)"),
         yaxis = list(title = "Bill Depth (mm)"))


p
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: You can use the configuration option `editable`. Interestingly, `editable` is defaulted to false. For example, to make it uneditable, `p %>% config(editable = F)`.

Comment: Never new about this functionality.